# Kubenete ingress controller doesn't let ssl passthrough when client request from different network

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ssl, ingress-controller

I've met a strange issue that it seems kubenete ingress controller doesn't let ssl passthrough when the client request from different network.

We have a kubenete server deployed on LAN, and configured the args --enable-ssl-passthrough in the ingress controller. When I did a test the ssl connection by using Curl or Openssl s_client through the LAN network, there was no issue => I can see the ssl connection works and the correct certificate presents from server side. The request is able to reach the pods.

But when I tested from the another network (VM on azue), I got tls connection issue and according to the result of openssl s_client, the certificat given by kubenete during the ssl handshake is the default fake one of kubenete ingress controller. By testing through Curl , I can see the 400 error in log of ingress controller pods.

I don't have any clue on the real cause. It just looks like that kube doesn't let ssl passthrough. Has anyone experienced the same issue or has some idea on that? Thanks!

Comment: While Stack Overflow does permit certain questions about Kubernetes, we require that they (like all questions asked here) be specifically related to programming. This question does not appear to be specifically related to programming, which makes it off-topic here. You might be able to ask questions like this one on [sf] or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/).